# Nexus4 USB Debugging Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, nexus-4, usb-debugging

I have a nexus4 and in developer options I switched on USB debugging.
After I connect it to my PC and press run from eclipse to test the app on my phone
the app does not run! 
The window shows the option only of them emulator but not of Nexus4 
I have nexus 4 drivers installed too.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you go a pressed "Build number" 7 times in the About Phone settings?

http://www.redmondpie.com/enable-developer-options-in-android-4.2-on-nexus-4-and-galaxy-nexus/

Comment: Yes I did that!
I figured out the problem! Since its a nexus device it needed google usb drivers rather than the company drivers!
Thanks but! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restart the Eclipse? because I had pretty much same issue with my galaxy s2.

Comment: Yes I installed google usb drivers for nexus 4 , restarted eclipse and then it worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact an issue I have faced for long.

Use the SDK on Linux. It works then. For me it doesn't work when on Windows....

Comment: ! 
It worked! You need to intstall Google drivers for nexus! 
Follow this!

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$ adb devices
```

and it should output something different than:

```
????????????
```

if not then you don't have permissions to access your device, you need to restart the adb daemon, in Linux you would use:

```
$ adb kill-server
```

and then run the daemon as root:

```
$ sudo adb start-server
```

after that you would be able to use it; I'm not sure how to do this on Windows but I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the drivers using the nexus 4 toolkit (you can find it on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1995688))